# Part of label text disappears after update

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi All I have a default label text in tkinter as shown in the first image which I want to update after I press a check button, however when I check the checkbutton, part of updated text disappears and overlaps the label image as shown in the second image. I am not sure why that is happening. Below is my sample code for demonstration.

[image: default]

[image: update]

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('./image.PNG'))
label = Label(root, text="(Range: 0 - 300)", image=img, compound=RIGHT)
label.place(x=60, y=190)

def data_check():
    if check_1.get() == 1:
        label.configure(text="No. (Range: 0 - 300)")

check_1 = IntVar()
cb = Checkbutton(root, variable = check_1, command=data_check)
cb.place(x=70, y=100)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @acw1668, you mean when you run, the full updated text shows?

Comment: I also could not reproduce the issue. It configured correctly.

Comment: It worked for me. No issue so far.